# How can I switch to another viewController in my swift app when user presses the button?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm working on authorization based on google accounts to my app. I have a settings view that contains the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Google

class Settings: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let background = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()
        background.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func didTapSignOut(sender: AnyObject) {

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

    }

}
```

and in the gui I have a button. When user clicks it then the session gets destroyed by this call: `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`. But, so far, nothing else happens and user is still in settings menu. I want to transfer him to my ViewController that contains log in form.

I tried to add the following code:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
}
```

but then the `window` is unresolved. How can I do it?

Comment: Please post the structure of your storyboard so I can help you out.

Comment: Check out my detailed response on why the window object is unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storyboard create a segue from the "Settings" ViewController to the "TabController" and set its identifier to "settingsToTabController". Then use the code `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("settingsToTabController", sender: self)` in the `didTapSignOut` function. I do not have a ton of experience with this so this may not be the best way of doing it, but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the original way you posted using the `window` variable you need to grab an instance of that window instance from your delegate. You can get it by doing let `window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!` and then setting the `UIStoryboard` to it as you did in your code above. Now your `window` object will not be unresolved.